# Detect Twebbrowser inputbox click in delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, input, selected

I am looking at creating autoform filler for Delphi, and obviously need a good method to capture which input boxes are the login boxes on each site so was wondering if I use a Twebbrowser component and load the page then click on the username and password boxes on the particular sites if  I can then extract the form name and input box names that I clicked on.

In Short I need delphi to capture the name of the selected input box on a web  page loaded into a twebbrowser component.

Any good methods to capture this information from the page loaded in a twebbrowser page would be appreciated!.

Comment: You want to do this for arbitrary pages

Comment: Yes David, basically I have hundreds of sites which are mostly art work related that I have signed up to over the years and am in the process of setting up a launchpad to access the sites easily without having to remember all the passwords or using a third party password utility. I can capture the forms and all the fields but want to just select each box for the Username and Password which could have a different  input box name on each site and for delphi to capture the name of the web form input boxes that I click on and then add them to a stringlist along with the page URL.

Comment: I had never gone into this before but believe that I need to detect which html element has focus in the twebbrowser loaded webpage and if it is an input box then capture the name of the input box and also the form name or Form number if the form has no name.

Comment: Here is a reference article trying to do something similar. http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=19

Comment: This may well be the method, so will have a play around, even though not very well versed in this.      (document as IHTMLDocument2).activeElement;

Comment: Another link with an implementation of similar, Thought I would post it here for reference by others who may be seeking a similar solution.  http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=163110.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, sorry David I did not notify you with the extra comments.

Comment: I cobbled together a solution that worked but am sure it can be improved on.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan
Here Is the code:-                                                                                                          

    procedure TForm5.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
    Document: IHTMLdocument2;
    MyEl:IHTMLElement;
    ElementName : OLEVariant;
    begin
       MyEl := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).activeElement;
           If MyEl.tagName = 'INPUT' then
             begin
                  ElementName := MyEl.getAttribute('Name', 0);
                  edit2.Text := ElementName;
             end;
    end;

Comment: Sorry about my formatting, new to posting here!.  Reduced version.                               procedure TForm5.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
    Document: IHTMLdocument2;
    MyEl:IHTMLElement;
    begin
       MyEl := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).activeElement;
           If MyEl.tagName = 'INPUT' then
             begin
                  edit2.Text := MyEl.getAttribute('Name', 0);
             end;
    end;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code shows how to find an INPUT element named 'input1':

```
var
  E : IHtmlElement;
  D : IHtmlDomNode;
  Doc2 : IHtmlDocument2;
  Doc3 : IHtmlDocument3;
  All : IHTMLElementCollection;
  i : Integer;

begin
  Doc3 := WebBrowser1.Document as IHtmlDocument3;
  D := Doc3.GetElementByID('input1') as IHtmlDomNode;
  if D <> Nil then begin
    ...
```

If you need to find more than one INPUT element or you wish to pattern-match the
name of the INPUT element(s), you can do this by retrieving the document's
IHtmlDocument2 interface and then iterating its `all` collection:

```
  Doc2 := WebBrowser1.Document as IHtmlDocument2;
  All := Doc2.all;
  for i := 0 to All.Length - 1 do begin
    E := All.Item(Null, i) as IHtmlElement;
    // Test E and do what you like with it
  end;
```

You could use a function like this to find the parent FORM element of an INPUT element

```
function GetParentFormElement(E : IHtmlElement) : IHtmlElement;
begin
  Result := Nil;
  while E <> Nil do begin
    if CompareText(E.tagName, 'form') = 0 then begin
      Result := E;
      exit;
    end;
    E := E.parentElement;
  end;
end;
```

and use it like this:

```
E := D as IHtmlElement;
E := GetParentFormElement(E);
Assert(E <> Nil);
```

> not all forms have a name or id so how do I get the number or reference of a parent form if there are a number of forms in a page?

Equally, not all `INPUT` elements are contained in a `FORM` one.  TBH, I don't know of a robust way of doing what you want which will survive a page's author making changes to it.  Anyway, there must be *some* way of identifying a given `INPUT` element, otherwise the server wouldn't be able to extract the user's response, mustn't there?  So it's just a question of figuring out what that might be for a particular page.  It it is not in the attributes of the element, then maybe you could look for the text of a nearby text element - after all, there must be some kind of prompt to the user to tell them what to fill in where.  But this is really a different issue than the substance of your original q, which I hope I have answered.  If you need more help on this specific point, I suggest you ask in a new q.  Make sure you include details (code) of what you've already tried, as qs lacking them tend not to be received well at SO.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Martyn, just the information I needed even though I have opted for the select element on page as I will be on the page when I need the information but I also need to find the number of the parent form of the input box that I select as well. How would I go about that?.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "number of the parent form", but I've added some code to my answer to show how to find an input box's parent form.  Presumably once you've found the form element, you can get the info you're after?

Comment: Just perfect for what I want to achieve Martyn, I will give it a try later and let you know how I got on!

Comment: The form number Martyn was if there are multiple forms on the page so I submit the correct form after adding the username and password fields.WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.Forms

Returns the collection of forms on the page.

.Length Returns the number of forms in the document.
.Item(0) Returns the first form.
Document equivalent:

var
  htmlDoc: IHTMLDocument2;
  allForms: IHTMLElementCollection;
  firstForm: IHTMLFormElement;
begin
  htmlDoc := WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  allForms := htmlDoc.Forms;
  firstForm := allForms.Item(0,'') as IHTMLFormElement;

Comment: As you can see I am having problems with formatting my code but reading up on that now..

Comment: @ MartynA, I managed to get the parent form name Martyn, but not all forms have a name or id so how do I get the number or reference of a parent form if there are a number of forms in a page?.

Comment: I accept that inputs may not have a form Martyn which is another scenario that I had not encompassed yet and think that what I need to find in the item index in the E := All.Item(Null, i) of the form. Not a lot of references to this method out there but lots of tag, name,id,class etc. Your input has been greatly appreciated and your answer to the current question accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about my formatting, new to posting here!. Reduced version.

```
procedure TForm5.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
Document: IHTMLdocument2;
MyEl: IHTMLElement;
begin
    MyEl := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).activeElement;
        If MyEl.tagName = 'INPUT' then
            begin
                 edit2.Text := MyEl.getAttribute('Name', 0);
            end;
end;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to your q, so you should really edit your q to include it and then delete this answer.  At SO, Answers are for answers to the q, not additions/afterthoughts/comments.  I've posted you an answer of my own in case you're still needing help.